# Easy way to install server config script and test without formatting

Tags: centos7

I am currently making scripts for clustering using `open hpc` . I uses centos and using docs I want to write a script.

But the thing is the script is supposed to be only running for one time configuration .

But I need to test each part requiring to format computer every time.

And formatting centos takes time like I need to completely destroy storage etc. Is it possible to clone same thing easily and restore it quickly

In those Windows XP days I used to test using Drive Snapshot but I am searching for linux alternatives

I  searched but it only gives manual installation which seems abit unfeasible isn't it.

Comment: This is a good case for virtual machines!

Comment: @MichaelHampton Yes but I am testing on real servers because virtual machine don't behave like real clustering .There is always problem like booting using network etc. Thanks

I even tried using docker but it didn't worked out. So i am searching easy way to format without configuring repeatedly saving me 10-20 mins :)

Comment: Then look into LVM snapshots.